# Getting infinite-scroll to trigger during scrolling, not just when buffer reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using Paul Irish's 'infinite-scroll' jquery plugin and it's working fine.

I want to be very aggressive with pre-firing so I've set my `bufferPx` param to `1000`.

When I scroll down far enough it's firing alright, however it will only fire after scrolling stops, if I give my scroll wheel a flick and get to the bottom before the wheel stops, the update wont fire until I've hit the bottom leaving me waiting for the next result set to appear.

My desired behaviour would be to have the update fire while I'm still actively scrolling so that if I'm quickly moving through my list I don't have to wait once I hit the bottom.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this, can I add a new event trigger, and if so what trigger would I use while scrolling is still active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the plugin https://raw.github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js, I would say that you need to modify the following code:

```
event.special.smartscroll = {
    setup: function () {
        $(this).bind("scroll", event.special.smartscroll.handler);
    },
    teardown: function () {
        $(this).unbind("scroll", event.special.smartscroll.handler);
    },
    handler: function (event, execAsap) {
        // Save the context
        var context = this,
        args = arguments;

        // set correct event type
        event.type = "smartscroll";

        if (scrollTimeout) { clearTimeout(scrollTimeout); }
        scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $.event.handle.apply(context, args);
        }, execAsap === "execAsap" ? 0 : 100);
    }
};
```

Make the edit on this line `}, execAsap === "execAsap" ? 0 : 100);`:

```
event.special.smartscroll = {
    setup: function () {
        $(this).bind("scroll", event.special.smartscroll.handler);
    },
    teardown: function () {
        $(this).unbind("scroll", event.special.smartscroll.handler);
    },
    handler: function (event, execAsap) {
        // Save the context
        var context = this,
        args = arguments;

        // set correct event type
        event.type = "smartscroll";

        if (scrollTimeout) { clearTimeout(scrollTimeout); }
        scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $.event.handle.apply(context, args);
        }, 0);
    }
};
```

**Explanation:** When you scroll down the page (either continuously or discretely), the 'scroll' event fires over and over again and calls the `handler: function(...)` in the code above. Inside of this method, a timer is set up `setTimeout` that will fire the appropriate infinite scroll code 100ms after the scroll event is triggered. However, this timer is also cancelled inside the method `{ clearTimeout(scrollTimeout); }`.

Therefore, as long as the user keeps scrolling, the timer keeps getting cleared and set again until the user stops scrolling. On the last scroll event, the timer is set and never cleared, so it will fire 100ms later and perform the content load. The edit I demonstrated above removes this waiting period and loads the content when the user gets to the bottom of the page (even if they are still actively scrolling).

*Caution: the author likely intended this timeout for performance issues, but you are welcome to test it in your configuration.*

Comment: Very much appreciated. I'm thinking I could avoid the performance hit by leaving a "working" flag open until the new content's dom content has been loaded, ignoring any further scrolling events while the flag is still open, rather than relying on the timer. It should hopefully keep the overhead low and would still accomplish the desired effect. Will obviously take some more tooling around, but this is what I was looking for, thanks again!